# How do you predict in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm a noob to tensorflow. So I was playing around with the Xor problem my question is how do you predict in tensorflow. So when i enter [1,0], i want it to give me either 1 or 0. Also in a different scenario if it is model which is meant to have more than multiple values(regressor)eg stocks. How would i do that Thank you.
So far i got this far:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=([4,2]), name = "Input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=([4,1]), name = "Output")
#weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,2], -1,1), name = "weights1")
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,1], -1,1), name = "weights2")
Biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]), name = "Biases1")
Biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name = "Biases2")
#Setting up the model
Node1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, W)+ Biases1)
Output = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Node1, w2)+ Biases2)
#Setting up the Cost function
cost = tf.reduce_mean(((y* tf.log(Output))+ 
                       ((1-y)* tf.log(1.0 - Output)))* -1)
#Now to training and optimizing
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
xorX = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
xorY = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])
#Now to creating the session
initial = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(initial)
for i in range(100000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: xorX, y: xorY })
```

Comment: It would help if you are a bit more specific: what do you mean by "predict"?

Comment: so basically i input 2 values so [1,0]. I want it to tell me 0 or 1 that all sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your classification is simply 0 iff Output<0.5 you can add new, prediction node:

```
prediction_op = tf.round(Output)
```

and call it afterwards

```
print(sess.run(prediction_op, feed_dict={X: np.array([[1., 0.]])}))
```

Comment: would you please explain what is happening as i am a total noob. Thanks

Comment: also how would you predict if it is a regression model like if there is more than two outputs for like stocks etc

Comment: you simply have to add to your graph operation that actually produces the output and run it in the session, since your graph produces probability from sigmoid, you could also just do sess.run on our Output node, I added "round" to make it a class. For regression you would simply run your Output node, that's all.

Comment: In regression wouldn't the output be the probability from sigmoid. Thank you

Comment: Please ask separate question and describe exactly what do you mean.